# counting list of objects. limiting possible added objects

Tags: c#, winforms, list, find, directive

I have 2 lists: groups and students. In a group list every group has an ID, and you select in from a comboBox when adding new student.
I need to assign between 2 and 4 students to each group.

I'm not sure how to limit amount of students in a group.

```
    private List<Student> students;
    private List<Group> groups;

    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Student student = new Student();

        student.StID = textStudentID.Text;
        student.StLName = textLastName.Text;
        student.AssignStudentToGroup(comboGroupID.Text);

        Group groupSelectedBox = groups.Find(x => x.GroupID == comboGroupID.Text);
        if (groupSelectedBox.Count <= 4)
        {
            students.Add(student);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Too many people");
        }


        ResetStudentViewGrid();
    }
```

I'm doing it in the button Add Student method, is it the appropriate place for checking the count?

Comment: @GrantWinney for some reason it gives me an error: Operator '<' can't be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'.

Comment: Use count as a method: .Count()

Comment: @devilfish17 ah thank you. but now it says that i'm missing a directive eve though i have using System.Linq; in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's where you're adding the new student, then yes I'd say it's appropriate.

If there's some chance you'll reuse this code elsewhere, you might want to put it all in a method named, say, `AddStudentToGroup()` and call that method from the click event.

Also, you'll want to change your `if` statement to

```
if (groupSelectedBox.Count < 4)
```

Otherwise, you're allowing 5 students in a group.